# How to get title, thumbnail and description of websites (Facebook/Twitter like preview) that have a cookie consent page?

Tags: php, web-crawler

What I want to do: Get the title, thumbnail picture and description of [this article](https://t3n.de/news/metaverse-plattformen-sandbox-decentraland-opensea-1442088/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=t3n-news) (German news website) for example.

When I post the link on Twitter/Facebook, they get all the right data for their preview.

When I use PHP curl or file_get_contents all I get is the data from the cookie consent page that appears when you first visit the website and did not yet accept their terms.

I haven't figured out how Twitter and Facebook are doing it. Any idea?

Do they maybe use special user agents or something like that? So that the cookie consent page isn't displayed in the first place?

Comment: https://meetedgar.com/blog/facebooks-new-link-previews-need-know-2018/ - does that help?

Answer (score 0):

1. Manually look for the cookie value in the inspector after accepting the cookie.
2. add a header to your scraper with the cookie value attached to it.

Comment: It might not be that easy, if they have implemented any additional restrictions such as browser fingerprinting, tied it to an IP address, or implemented similar measures.

Comment: Also, this might work for one page. But not for all. Do you really think Facebook and Twitter are constantly grabbing and saving those cookies?

Comment: @Hillcow No... but the person asking the question is not facebook nor twitter. They are whitelisted to scrape the meta tags. I asked the op to do this to see if adding the cookie would be enough. After testing he could have had  curl request to get the cookies and put those in curl cookie jar and scrape the page, or won't that work?